# React run something on the next render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an uncontrolled child component and I'm running into trouble making the save feature. (sadly, I could not find any way to make it controlled; it is a text box made by using a crude content-editable workaround, which is the best I could do for my case).

Parent

```
const [text, setText] = useState('');
const save = () => {
    makeAPICall(text);
};
...
return <Child initialText={text} setText={setText} save={save} />
```

Child

```
handleClick = () => {
    props.setText(myText)
    props.save();
};
```

The problem is that the `text` in Parent is not immediately updated, so it calls Parent's `save` with the old state. I want to run `save` next render with updated `text` in Parent. Is this possible?

Currently, my workaround is I have a `saveFlag` and `useEffect(..., [saveFlag])`, but it might become very confusing later and I'm wondering if there is something better.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could just pass the text by function parameters:

Parent

```js
const save = (text) => {
    makeAPICall(text);
};
```

Child

```js
handleClick = () => {
    props.setText(myText)
    props.save(myText);
};
```